# cannot able to change css of dynamic button created in js file using jquery 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Created the button template, don't mind about **item** variable it is just to give an unique id to every button.

```
var html = "<button  id='"+item+"' onclick='change_color("+item+"); buttonClicked("+item+")' style='width:60px;border-style:none; background-color: transparent;padding-right:10px;margin-right:10px;'><i class='fa fa-power-off fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
```

Append in html file.

```
$("#"+item).append(html);
```

then I create two onclick function

```
change_color = function(item)
{
    alert(item);
    $("#"+item).find('i').css("color","red");
}
```

The Alert is working, whenever I click on button; it shows correct id, but before changing the color it moved to the next function which is **buttonClicked()**

Comment: Can you create a snippet of your problem??

Comment: you html is malformed, you need to close your `<button />` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the two functions inline, you should call the second function from the first one.

```
change_color = function(item)
{
   alert(item);
   $("#"+item).find('i').css("color","red");
   buttonClicked("foobar");
}
```